# why is pandas's isin method returning False for matching None?

Tags: python, pandas, isin

Suppose i have two equivalent dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None, None, None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None, None, None]})
```

When i use the isin method as such:

```
df1.isin(df2)
```

I get the following output:

|  | 'a' |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | False |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |

I would expect the results to be True for all. Why am I not getting my expected results?

Appreciate any guidance and clarifications from the community, thanks!

Comment: None is not equal to None. cant be compared, hence False

Answer (score 0):

It's because pandas converts the `None` into `np.nan`, while:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>>
```

Gives `False`.

It's because `np.nan` is setup that all `np.nan`s are different objects, `np.nan` is inherited from pythons `float('nan')`, as you can see:

```
>>> id(float('nan'))
1881571529008
>>> id(float('nan'))
1881618531856
>>>
```

They're different objects!

An example implementation for `np.nan != np.nan` could be:

```
class nan:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'nan'
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
print(nan() == nan())
print(nan())
```

Output:

```
False
nan
```

Comment: The id is compared with `is`. `==` uses the equality operator. Presumably `np.nan` has `def __eq__(self, other): return False`

Comment: @Acccumulation yeap exactly!